# EF connection string with _ in database name will not connect

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6 Code First.

I have a database named: LA_ARI

I'm unable to connect to this database.

I can connect to any other database that does not have an underscore ( _ ) in the db name.

Does EF support connecting to databases with an underscore in the name?

Comment: Yes, EF supports connecting to databases with an underscore in the name. I have 3 databases I use at the moment with underscores in them. I suspect you have a different issue. Maybe a permissions problem?

Comment: In your cn str did you wrap the name in brackets like this [LA_ARI] or just pass the name without brackets LA_ARI?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm using EF 6 Code First.  Are you using Code First?

Comment: what does your connectionstring look like? maybe you forgot escaping.

Comment: Found the problem.  Had the wrong defaultConnectionFactory.  Changed to SqlClient now working, even with _ in DB name.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  Had the wrong defaultConnectionFactory.  Changed to SqlClient now working, even with _ in DB name.